# Which is the strongest bond?

Tags: bond

Between ionic, covalent and metallic, which is the strongest? 
I got really confused looking up on the internet, and found a lot of contradictory informations.

If I have to evaluate the strongest bond, maybe given a list of molecules, what do I do?

Comment: There is no definitive answer. For a given molecule, you determine the Gibbs free energy of formation relative to standard state precursors. Uniquely determining that a given bond is ionic, covalent, or metallic is either really hard or impossible.

Comment: Strong covalent bond is pretty strong. Weak covalent bond is pretty weak. There is no such thing as bond strength of a covalent bond. Ditto for other types.

Comment: @JonCuster but if I need to determinate which one between some given molecules is the strongest, how do I tell?

Answer (score 0):

To determine the relative bond strength difference, between any two atoms pairs. You can simply look up the measured bond strengths in kj/mol, or eV, at STP and directly compare. These values can be found in tables in every chemistry textboom.